# WinDbg cannot find symbols for ntdll on MS symbol server

Tags: windbg

I'm trying to debug executable notepad.exe (from Windows 10 distribution), and symbols ntdll.pdb from Microsoft symbols server are required, but debugger returns an error that they cannot find file specified:

```
0:000> .reload
Reloading current modules
.................................
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x25
         http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         ntdll.pdb
         BC08E2B7EBB349A18DCE18BE9AA6660E1
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/ntdll.pdb/BC08E2B7EBB349A18DCE18BE9AA6660E1/ntdll.pdb
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 404 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/ntdll.pdb/BC08E2B7EBB349A18DCE18BE9AA6660E1/ntdll.pd_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 404 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/ntdll.pdb/BC08E2B7EBB349A18DCE18BE9AA6660E1/file.ptr

SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 404 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\ntdll.pdb\BC08E2B7EBB349A18DCE18BE9AA6660E1\ntdll.pdb - file not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/ntdll.pdb/BC08E2B7EBB349A18DCE18BE9AA6660E1/ntdll.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\ntdll.pdb\BC08E2B7EBB349A18DCE18BE9AA6660E1\ntdll.pdb not found
DBGHELP: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: ntdll.pdb - file not found
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ntdll.dll - 
DBGHELP: ntdll - export symbols

************* Symbol Loading Error Summary **************
Module name            Error
SharedUserData         No error - symbol load deferred
                Symbol loading has been deferred because this symbol is not needed
                at this time. Use reload /f to force load symbols.

ntdll                  The system cannot find the file specified : http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
                The SYMSRV client failed to find a file in the UNC store, or there
                is an invalid UNC store (an invalid path or the pingme.txt file is
                not present in the root directory), or the file is present in the
                symbol server exclusion list.
```

Is it possible that MS server does not contain required symbols?

It is: version 10.0.14393.447 (rs1_release_inmarket.161102-0100)

Comment: ok, there seams to be an issue. I'll contact my Microsoft contacts

Comment: MS investigates the issue now. They know of 4 Windows 10 builds where the symbols are missing

Comment: try again. PDB is now online

Comment: does it work now or not? Asking a question but never give any feedback is confusing for people that try to help you.

Comment: I gave it up after 1 week. Looks like you don't want help or why don't you reply to any comment? I'll no longer help you. Bye

Answer (score 0):

The NTDLL.PDB (`ntdll.pdb\BC08E2B7EBB349A18DCE18BE9AA6660E1\ntdll.pdb`) is now online and I was able to get the PDB:

```
00007ffb`c79c0000 00007ffb`c7b91000   ntdll      
(pdb symbols) d:\sym\dl\nt\ntdll.pdb\BC08E2B7EBB349A18DCE18BE9AA6660E1\ntdll.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: ntdll.dll
    Image path: C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
    Image name: ntdll.dll
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Wed Nov  2 11:13:06 2016 (5819BC32)
    CheckSum:         001DA569
    ImageSize:        001D1000
    File version:     10.0.14393.447
    Product version:  10.0.14393.447
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    InternalName:     ntdll.dll
    OriginalFilename: ntdll.dll
    ProductVersion:   10.0.14393.447
    FileVersion:      10.0.14393.447 (rs1_release_inmarket.161102-0100)
    FileDescription:  NT Layer DLL
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

So try again to load the symbols.

Comment: Symbols mismatch again, ntdll sig: F999943D-F7FB-4B8E-B6D9-9F2B047BC310, pdb sig: BC08E2B7-EBB3-49A1-8DCE-18BE9AA6660E

Comment: Fails with SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 502 - HTTP_STATUS_BAD_GATEWAY

Comment: @kerem which version do you have? Also 10.0.14393.447? x86 or x64 DLL/PDB?

Comment: 10.0.14393.447 in a x86 dump.

Comment: @kerem 32Bit PDB is also online and I was able to get it: d:\sym\dl\nt\ntdll.pdb\54547451B98D4B16A5CF54941D74CD881\ntdll.pdb

Comment: chksym shows the signature as F999943D-F7FB-4B8E-B6D9-9F2B047BC310 and pdb as wntdll.pdb. Could you share result of !chksym ntdll in windbg?

Comment: @kerem **pdb sig: 54547451-B98D-4B16-A5CF-54941D74CD88** PDb and dll match. I created a dump of a 32Bit Win10. Do you use x64 Win10 and run 32Bit notepad? Which tool have you used to create the dump? Taskmgr must be also 32bit if 32bit notepad. otherwise the dump is 64bit and you have issues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129059/discussion-between-kerem-and-magicandre1981).