# How to fix “No matching binary found” for Microsoft dll in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, dll, crash-dumps

I have a crash dump received of my application from customer to analyze, but Visual Studio 2017 is unable to load most of the Microsoft dll symbols for this crash dump:

```
…
'dump_11_10_2023-14_24_55_0.dmp' (Minidump) : Chargé '*C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Binaire correspondant introuvable. [No matching binary found]
'dump_11_10_2023-14_24_55_0.dmp' (Minidump) : Chargé '*C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Binaire correspondant introuvable.
'dump_11_10_2023-14_24_55_0.dmp' (Minidump) : Chargé '*C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll'. Binaire correspondant introuvable.
'dump_11_10_2023-14_24_55_0.dmp' (Minidump) : Chargé '*C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Binaire correspondant introuvable.
…
'dump_11_10_2023-14_24_55_0.dmp' (Minidump) : Chargé 'C:\Users\[…]\Qt5Multimedia.dll'. Les symboles ont été chargés. [Symbols have been loaded]
'dump_11_10_2023-14_24_55_0.dmp' (Minidump) : Chargé 'C:\Users\[…]\boost_system.dll'. Les symboles ont été chargés.
…
```

I have generated a crash dump on my computer for the same application, and the Microsoft dll symbols are successfully loaded from Microsoft symbols server.

Notable differences between the customer dump and my dump are:

- the system version: 10.0.17763 (customer) vs 10.0.19045 (mine)
- the dll versions, customer:

```
ntdll.dll   C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll   6.2.17763.2989
kernel32.dll    C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll    6.2.17763.2989
KERNELBASE.dll  C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll  6.2.17763.2989
user32.dll  C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll  6.2.17763.2989
win32u.dll  C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll  6.2.17763.1
gdi32.dll   C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll   6.2.17763.1697
…
```

mine:

```
ntdll.dll   C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll   6.2.19041.3393
kernel32.dll    C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll    6.2.19041.3393
KERNELBASE.dll  C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll  6.2.19041.3448
user32.dll  C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll  6.2.19041.3448
win32u.dll  C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll  6.2.19041.3448
gdi32.dll   C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll   6.2.19041.3393
…
```

I did a search on Internet and found a [topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40578762/windbg-cannot-find-symbols-for-ntdll-on-ms-symbol-server) with a user named magicandre1981 answering the symbols were missing on Microsoft server and that he will contact his Microsoft contacts to fix it.

How can check my issue is the same, that is to say how can I check the symbols I need are missing on the Microsoft server?

After I guess I should ask Microsoft but I have no idea where on Microsoft’s websites I could do that, so how should I contact Microsoft for such an issue?

Comment: It is not complaining about symbols, it simply can't find the operating system DLLs so can't tell you anything about the code they contain.  Most minidump takers omit them, on the assumption that everybody uses the same Windows version.  You don't.  Telling your customer to keep their Win10 install updated is not unreasonable.

Comment: Microsoft symbol server is usually providing both the pdb and the dll for Microsoft dlls. I currently have other dumps from other Windows  version, without the matching MS dlls and Visual Studio just downloaded them from MS server.

Comment: Customer system is never connected to Internet, they seldomely upgrade it as they have to do it through USB keys.